# canLoad does not prevent component load

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular app with routes that implement `canLoad: [AuthGuard]`,
and canLoad is in my AuthGuard class like so:

```
    canLoad(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): 
    boolean 
   {
     if (this.authService.isLogged || this.authService.checkLoggedIn()) 
     {
      return true;
     } else
     {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return 
     } 
   }
```

If I try to access any of my routes while not logged in, I constantly get errors because the route's components still run `NgOnInit()` without any routing information, so I end up making API calls with no arguments. The page, however, always navigates to `/login`.

I'm not exactly clear on how AuthGuard works, but I set breakpoints on the `canLoad()` function and they don't ever get triggered. Am I doing something wrong here?

Here's the root route in question:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: MydocsComponent,
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    children: [...]
}
```

EDIT: I have realized that this was an issue with my `this.authService.checkLoggedIn()` method - namely that it would redirect users to `/login` prior to being checked by the AuthGuard, so this is an issue on my end. Thanks for the assistance and I hope the answer below helps some people using `canLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

`canLoad` is used with `lazily-loaded` modules to prevent loading the chunk if the condition fails. If you want to limit access to a component, use `canActivate` guard.

Check this [summary](https://angular.io/guide/router#the-sample-application)